# Error using Rational Asset Manager with Oracle 11g

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, websphere

Using Rational Asset Manager 7.5.4.1 version with Oracle 11.g on WAS 8.5.5.13 I am getting following oracle error?

While we see the logs we get following SQL error code.

> SQL Error Code is 17008 SQL State is :08003

Other log trace says like below.

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException 
    java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection 
    com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: Closed Connection 
    com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: IO Error: Socket read interrupted
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error usually is caused due to network issue or firewall issues.

To root cause and eliminate those:
1. You can check AWR and other connectivity reports
2. Ping works between app server and DB host
3. Required configurations for sqlnet.ora parameters time out are set correctly.

If none of them fix the issue, it worth to check jdbc jar file and its version.

In this case i think solution is to use jdbc6.jar and checking if there is any mismatch in the version of the jar that is presently used.